# Plot one-dimensional list of points in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with numbers:

```
1
4
9
...
```

I want to plot a depencency of the numbers from their order position in the file (points [(1,1); (2;4); (3; 9); ...]).

How can I do it with gnuplot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

`plot "filename.txt" using ($0+1):1`

$0 is the index of entries but it starts at 0 so we simlpy add 1 to it.

Tell me if this works for you!